# Error while running nodelet: cannot load library, undefined symbol

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a nodelet out of an existing node
with the header file gridmapping_nodelet.h given as

```
#ifndef GRIDMAPIING_NODELET_H
#define GRIDMAPIING_NODELET_H
#include <gridmapping/gridprocess.h>
#include <missiondata/dem.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>

//namespace TX
//{

namespace gridmapping_nodelet
{

  class gridmapping : public nodelet::Nodelet
  {
     public:
     gridmapping(){};
     virtual void onInit();
     ~gridmapping();
     private:
     ros::NodeHandle * n;
     double maxrange;
     double cellsize;
     int gridsize;
     TX::GridProcess* process;
     
  //subcribe to pose and lidar data
     ros::Subscriber pose;
     ros::Subscriber points;
     ros::Subscriber points2;
     ros::Subscriber stereo;

  //set publish frequency
     ros::Timer obst_publish_timer;
     ros::Timer marker_publish_timer;
  };
};
//};

#endif
```

and gridmapping_nodelet.cpp file is as follows

```
     #include <gridmapping_nodelet/gridmapping_nodelet.h>
     #include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>

     // watch the capitalization carefully

     PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(gridmapping_nodelet, gridmappingn,gridmapping_nodelet::gridmapping, nodelet::Nodelet)    

     using namespace gridmapping_nodelet;

       void gridmapping_nodelet::gridmapping::onInit()
       {
           *n = getNodeHandle();
           n->getParam("/gridmapping/maxrange", maxrange);
           n->getParam("/gridmapping/cellsize", cellsize);

           gridsize = (6*maxrange)/cellsize;
           
           //this does the publishing and data processing
           process = new TX::GridProcess(*n, cellsize, maxrange, gridsize);
           //process = new TX::GridProcess(*n, 20, 400, 100);
           //subcribe to pose and lidar data
           pose = n->subscribe("/gridmapping/pose",0, & TX::GridProcess::updatePose, process);
           points = n->subscribe("/gridmapping/cloud", 5,& TX::GridProcess::updateGrid, process);
           points2 = n->subscribe("/gridmapping/cloud2", 5,& TX::GridProcess::updateGrid2, process);
           stereo = n->subscribe("/gridmapping/stereocloud", 5, & TX::GridProcess::updateGridStereo, process);
           
           //set publish frequency
           obst_publish_timer = n->createTimer(ros::Duration(0.25), &TX::GridProcess::publishObstacles, process);
           marker_publish_timer = n->createTimer(ros::Duration(0.25), &TX::GridProcess::publishMarkers, process);         
           
       }
```

nodelet_plugins.xml is given by

```
<library path="lib/libgridmapping">
<class name="gridmapping_nodelet/gridmappingn" type="gridmapping_nodelet::gridmapping" base_class_type="nodelet::Nodelet">
<description>
 This is gridmapping nodelet.
</description>
</class>
</library>
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
rosbuild_add_library(gridmapping src/gridmapping_nodelet.cpp)
```

manifest.xml

```
<export>
 <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -lgridmapping" />
 <nodelet plugin="${prefix}/nodelet_plugins.xml" />
</export>
```

launch file

```
  <launch>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet"  args="manager" output="screen"/>

    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="gridmapping" args="load gridmapping_nodelet/gridmappingn standalone_nodelet" output="screen">
    </node>                 
  </launch>
```

The parameters are defined in a separate launch file which calls on the launch file mentioned above.

The ouput error is  as follows

```
[ERROR] [1323458052.686296083]: Failed to load nodelet [/gridmapping] of type  [gridmapping_nodelet/gridmappingn]: Failed to load library /home/aeroscout/ros/tx_stacks/tx_perception/gridmapping_nodelet/lib/libgridmapping.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /home/aeroscout/ros/tx_stacks/tx_perception/gridmapping_nodelet/lib/libgridmapping.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2TX11GridProcess11updateGrid2ERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs12PointCloud2_ISaIvEEEEE
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
EDIT 1
```

Alright the library issue is resolved, thanks to Tully!
But now I am facing md5sum errors, I have checked all my packages for consistency in terms in messages(by rebuilding them after clean) and the node I am converting to nodelet runs just fine. Since I don't change message types during conversion, I was surprised to see this error in the log file after my nodelet crashed -

```
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,390] [thread 0x7f6100734760]: [DEBUG] UDPROS server listening on port [55235]
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,394] [thread 0x7f6100734760]: [DEBUG] Started node [/standalone_nodelet], pid [25828], bound on [jetson], xmlrpc port [34923], tcpros port [50619], logging to [/home/aeroscout/.ros/log/72e257c2-2763-11e1-8888-003067cb59a6/standalone_nodelet-12.log], using [real] time
     [ros.nodelet] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,397] [thread 0x7f6100734760]: [INFO] Initializing nodelet with 10 worker threads.
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,414] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] Accepted connection on socket [7], new socket [11]
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,414] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] TCPROS received a connection from [127.0.1.1:45144]
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,414] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] Connection: Creating ServiceClientLink for service [/standalone_nodelet/load_nodelet] connected to [callerid=[/gridmapping] address=[TCPROS connection to [127.0.1.1:45144 on socket 11]]]
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,414] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] Service client [/gridmapping] wants service [/standalone_nodelet/load_nodelet] with md5sum [*]
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,414] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] Socket [11] received 0/4 bytes, closing
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,414] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] TCP socket [11] closed
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,415] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] Accepted connection on socket [7], new socket [11]
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,415] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] TCPROS received a connection from [127.0.1.1:45146]
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,415] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] Connection: Creating ServiceClientLink for service [/standalone_nodelet/load_nodelet] connected to [callerid=[/gridmapping] address=[TCPROS connection to [127.0.1.1:45146 on socket 11]]]
     [roscpp_internal] [2011-12-15 16:26:31,415] [thread 0x7f60f9d4e700]: [DEBUG] Service client [/gridmapping] wants service [/standalone_nodelet/load_nodelet] with md5sum [8cfbf33bf3fbd4c54a833f6e2b105331]
```

I have also tried remaking the ros nodelet package but without any success.

Thanks for your time and help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12293/error-while-running-nodelet:-cannot-load-library,-undefined-symbol/) by [Sankalp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1516/sankalp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to link the library against the library containing GridProcess symbols.  If it's in another package you should add the library to the exports in the other packages [manifest.xml](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest) and make sure that you depend on that package.  If it's in the same package you need to use the "target_link_libraries" cmake command in you CmakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sankalp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1516/sankalp/) on 2011-12-14**:
Thanks for your answer, Although I was including gridmapping libraries but it had the same library name as gridmapping_nodelet and that was causing the issue above. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-27**:
Thanks for the information. I am facing similar kind of problem (First error), even after adding the proper src file. Can you please check once? http://answers.ros.org/question/157886/error-while-loading-nodelet-velocity_multiplexer/